# Postgres trigger query perfomance with LOOP and RAISE

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Consider following `before_update` validation trigger on `contracts` table:

```
FOR i IN
     SELECT uuid FROM tb_some_orders 
     WHERE is_deleted = 0 AND uuid_contract = NEW.uuid
LOOP
     RAISE '#is_deleted#:deleting is prohibited due to dependent objects';
END LOOP;
```

`tb_some_orders` will contain about 1 mil of rows

What should happen, will db fetch all records or read each record or one by one?

Is there any need for `LIMIT 1` as I do in app code?

Comment: You shouldn't use a FOR loop for this to begin with. A single SELECT statement with an `exists` condition will be way more efficient. In fact, a properly declared foreign key constraint would be a much better alternative to get rid of the trigger entirely.

Comment: are you saying that deletion should be always hard delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will read the rows one by one using a cursor. So in your case, reading will stop after the first row has been fetched, because you throw an exception.

It might still be a good idea to add `LIMIT 1`, so that the optimizer knows that it should plan the query so that the first row can be returned as fast as possible.

In the present case, the most idiomatic way to write that would be

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tb_some_orders 
           WHERE is_deleted = 0
             AND uuid_contract = NEW.uuid)
THEN
    RAISE '#is_deleted#:deleting is prohibited due to dependent objects';
END IF;
```

The `EXISTS` will also stop executing as soon as it finds the first result row, and the syntax makes the purpose obvious.

Comment: shouldn't it stop fetching at RAISE?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see the `RAISE`. I have improved the answer.